# Сложность алгоритма Шенхаге — Штрассена

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Сложность алгоритма Шенхаге—Штрассена — `O(nlog(n)loglog(n))`.
`nlog(n)` понятно откуда — мы запускаем БПФ туда и обратно — это `O(nlog(n))`, потом перемножаем числа, это `O(n)`, потом мы выравниваем коэффициенты — еще `O(n)`.
А вот откуда там `loglog(n)` берется? Я ошибся с расчетом сложности БПФ? Или что-то еще?

Comment: Арифметическая сложность этого алгоритма [`O(n\*log(n))`](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1317469), а приведенная вами сложность - это [битовая сложность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F)), она немного отличается от арифметической

P.S. это не ответ, а комментарий, т.к. ответа на вопрос я не знаю )

Comment: Возможно, тут учитывается расход на реально огромные числа. Если ваше число имеет порядок `n`, то оно содержит порядка `log n` бит. Представьте себе указатель на этой системе. Чтобы адресовать `X` бит, нужно `log X` бит указателя. Для `X = log n` получаем размер указателя `log log n`. Операции на настолько длинных указателях по идее занимают не константное время, а время, пропорциональное длине указателя.

Comment: Из [TAOCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming)/4.3.3:

> If we allow ourselves a more powerful computer, with random access to any number of words of bounded size, Schönhage has pointed out that the upper bound drops to `O(n log n)`.

Что судя по всему подтверждает моё преположение.

Comment: Похоже, вы правы. Переведите комментарий в ответ, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пусть число в двоичной форме занимает `n`бит - это многочлен, представляемый битовым массивом коэффициентов. Перемножение двух чисел эквивалентно линейной свёртке этих массивов.
Быстрый алгоритм циклической свёртки двух массивов имеет вид:

**a(*)b = FFT<sup>-1</sup>(FFT(a)FFT(b)).**

Он превращается в алгоритм линейной свёртки при дополнении массивов нулевыми коэффициентами до степени результата (если разрядности чисел одинаковы, это удвоенная разрядность).

FFT имеет сложность `O(nlogn)` операций. При этом на каждый новый элемент приходится `O(logn)` операций сложения с весами, что повышает разрядность c `1` бита до `O(log log n)`.
FFT<sup>-1</sup> имеет сложность того же порядка.
Переносы битов через разряды - это n сложений разрядности `O(log log n)`.
Перемножение спектров - это n умножений разрядности `O(log log n)`, сложность каждого умножения не выше O(log<sup>2</sup> log n).

Битовая сложность по операциям:

2 прямых FFT: O(n log(n) log(log(n)))

Перемножение спектров: O(n log<sup>2</sup>(log(n)))

FFT<sup>-1</sup>: O(n log(n) log(log(n))).

Переносы битов через разряды: O(O(n log(n) log(log(n))))

Итого: **O(n log(n) log(log(n)))**.